# cURL not run in xampp v5.6.3

Tags: apache, curl, xampp

I try to run cURL in xampp v5.6.3 (PHP 5.6.3) last version,

In **xampp/php/php.ini**

**extension=php_curl.dll** is without **;**

other php.ini i can't found in this new version of xampp,

when i try test from this http://www.mattsbits.co.uk/item-164.html
I get error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\check_curl.php on line 16**

cURL isn't returning anything, anyone know solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late with answer but i had the same issue. I recommend downgrading a bit. My old php version was 5.5.15, curl seems to work there just fine.